# jQuery selector for current row clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am performing some action on a row click of a table. Basically appending a new table on a row click.

```
$('#myTable').on('click-row.bs.table', function (e, row, $element) {

       ///...some actions

    $('#myTable> tbody:last').append('<table id="newTable" class="table table-hover table-condensed table-bordered">' + thead + tbody + '</table>');
}
```

How do I ensure that the new table is added just below the row clicked and not at the last position(row)?

Comment: Did you know [`insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/) ? Anyway, a `table` after a row(`td`) isn't valid. Or I get you wrong?

Comment: i guess i can remove the table.....can you provide a reply with insertAfter()

Comment: i cannot remove the table as I am binding new head tags.

Comment: Can you update your question with a symbolic html example of the result you want?

Comment: It's a bit difficult to know precisely what you're trying to accomplish, but perhaps something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/47ux6kjd/1/)?

Comment: How about a `<tr><table>` structure..works fine.....i just want to be able to add the row after the current row click and not at the las

Comment: @thewatcheruatu $(this).after(...) is doing nothing

Comment: and i want to accomplish what you have done in the fiddle..